# Targeting announcements Starburst gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am using [Starburst](https://github.com/csm123/starburst) gem to show announcements upon user login. There is an option to limit the users

```
Starburst::Announcement.create(
    :body => 'Upgrade to platinum and save 10% with coupon code XYZ!',
    :limit_to_users => 
    [
        {
            :field => "subscription",
            :value => "gold"
        }
    ]
)
```

Is there any way to pass multiple values for a field like this:

```
{
  :field => "subscription",
  :value => ["gold","silver"]
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Currently Starburst doesn't support 'or' in queries. Your best bet is to create a method on your user class and use that for targeting, which will achieve the same result.

Add to the User class:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

 def gold_or_silver
    subscription == "gold" || subscription == "silver"
 end

end
```

Then enable the method in config/initializers/starburst.rb (create it if it does not already exist):

```
Starburst.configuration do |config|
    config.user_instance_methods  = ["gold_or_silver"]  '
end
```

Then in filtering the message:

```
Starburst::Announcement.create(
    :body => 'Upgrade to platinum and save 10% with coupon code XYZ!',
    :limit_to_users => 
    [
        {
            :field => "silver_or_gold",
            :value => true
        }
    ]
)
```